# how to add text in top border of view in andriod

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin-extension, ui-design

I am new to android development please help me in creating this type design
I want to add text in the center of the top borders in the card
[image]

please help me or guide me to achive the same view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at he reference code available here

[CountDownTimerView](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17jh3FF7O1ezDYNBf85gY31u4vu-jfI5y/view?usp=drivesdk)

Make changes according to your need.

Happy Coding

Comment: Always ready to help 

Answer (score 1):

in TextView

```
android:hint="@string/name"
```

**Example**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="none"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but my requirment is not input feild like i have come up with differnent solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_border_offer"
    >   
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Offer ends in"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white"
    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
      android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```